# What's the difference in using Pause/Stop in µTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

Is there any technical difference in choosing Pause or Stop button to block the download of a torrent in µTorrent?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**The user manual states:**

Pause will pause the selected torrent job(s), but won't actually stop it. This tells µTorrent to attempt to retain connections to peers without having to re-establish them like starting stopped torrent jobs would require. It is useful for when you need quick access to bandwidth. Realize that while µTorrent won't drop the connections on its own accord, the connection can still get dropped by the client on the other end of the connection.

Stop will stop the selected torrent job(s). All connections with peers are dropped.

Comment: I've noticed that "pause" takes a little while to slow down the download rate to a stop, but "stop" does so instantly. Do you know if "pause" is finishing started "packets" or something like that?

Comment: "stop" closes the connections after the current packets have been send, I guess that "pause" would pause the connections after the current pieces have been sent. One piece can be compared to multiple packets.